# В гости: какой падеж?

Tags: падежи, наречия

Сочетание слов *в гости* имеет все признаки наречной группы, но ведь изначально эта группа строится по схеме *предл. + сущ.*

Возникает вопрос, в каком падеже тогда стоит слово *гости*? Мне кажется, что это *винительный неодушевлённый*, т. к. слово *гости* здесь употребляется не в значении *"группа людей",* а в значении места, локации — *"не дома, в гостях".*

Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

С таким подходом не согласна. Падеж, конечно, винительный - куда? Так как это, как Вы справедливо сказали, наречная группа, то вопрос *в кого? во что?* выглядит странно и нам не поможет. Как и *пришёл откуда? из гостей* - глагол управляет родительным падежом, хотя вопрос из кого? из чего? не поставишь.

Одушевлённость/неодушевлённость - категория грамматическая, не всегда совпадающая с нашим видением живого/неживого. Например, покойник и труп одинаково воспринимаются как неживое, но при этом покойник-одушевлённое сущ., а труп - неодушевлённое.

Вспомним, что различие существительных одушевленных и неодушевленных грамматически выражается в том, что при склонении существительных во множественном числе форма винительного падежа у имен существительных одушевленных совпадает с формой родительного падежа (нет мальчиков, девочек — вижу мальчиков, девочек; **нет гостей - вижу гостей**), а у имен существительных неодушевленных — с формой именительного падежа ( нет улиц, домов — вижу улицы, дома). У имен существительных мужского рода (кроме существительных на -а, -я) различение одушевленности и неодушевленности последовательно проводится также и в единственном числе (взял котенка, но купил стул; **вижу гостя).**

Принадлежность имен существительных к одушевленным или неодушевленным обозначается еще и формами согласующихся с ними имен прилагательных: прилагательные, согласованные с существительными одушевленными, образуют форму винительного падежа, сходную с родительным падежом, а согласованные с существительными неодушевленными — сходную с формой именительного падежа: увидел молодого друга; купил большого карася — увидел молодой месяц; купил большой стол. Вижу дорогого гостя - совпадает с родительным падежом.

Имена существительные одушевленные при глаголах поступить, произвести, вступить, пойти и некоторых других, обозначающих переход в другое состояние или положение, в конструкции с предлогом **в** имеют винительный падеж множественного числа, совпадающий по форме с именительным: произвести в офицеры, поступить в актеры, пойти в лётчики; **пойти в гости.** При этом **категория одушевлённости не меняется, она постоянна.** Хотя в русском языке есть примеры, когда неодушевлённое существительное используется в соответствующих контекстах как одушевлённое: считать звёзды - видел многих звёзд эстрады. Но это не тот случай.

Answer (score 1):

***Я пришел к ним в гости.***

***В гости*** — это В.п., форма которого (**в виде исключения для одуш. сущ.**) совпадает с формой И.п.

Значение падежа — **вхождение в группу лиц** (произвести в офицеры, взять в свидетели, **проситься в помощники**, метить в генералы).

Сравнить:

(1) *напроситься в гости* (войти в группу гостей) — здесь глагол управляет существительным;

(2) прийти в гости — здесь глагол уже не управляет существительным, **существительное переходит  в наречие**.

Но значение **вхождения в группу** сохраняется и у наречия,  а пространственное значение ***куда*** выражается падежной формой ***к ним*** (в их дом).

Получается: *Я пришел к ним в гости. — Я пришел в качестве их гостя (в их дом)*.

**Таким образом, делаем ВЫВОД.**

1) Форма ***в гости***  может быть или **существительным** в В.п. (напроситься в гости), или **чаще наречием** (прийти в гости).

2) О значении наречия ***в гости***: прийти куда? — к ним, прийти как?  в качестве кого? — в гости.  Это значение **обстоятельства образа действия**, а не места.